# Do Heart-to-Hearts provide some bonus?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Heart-to-Heart events are really good for getting to know characters, yet I'm curious if they provide any other bonuses.

In first Xenoblade Chronicles, H2H improved relationships between characters, increasing their affinity. The sequel does not feature affinity between characters, only affinity between Blade and Driver. Despite this, not all H2Hs are between Blade and Driver. (E.g. there is a Heart-to-Heart between Nia and Morag)

Is there any benefit to Heart-to-Hearts, not counting story and blade skill unlocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, in XC2, heart to hearts involving only drivers do not affect anything - it's just a bit of comedic relief and character development.

**However**, heart to hearts between blades and drivers will increase affinity between blade and driver. This can also unlock certain nodes on the affinity tree.

Comment: The game seems to contradict this... one of the informants suggests that they increase trust (presumably only with the 'main' blades or unique blades if they get them) and that the answers given effect the outcome...

Comment: @adaliabooks that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you your second paragraph was just about the game in general rather than the heart to hearts specifically.

Comment: @adaliabooks I’ve edited the answer to make it more clear that some heart to hearts have an effect

Comment: The DLC blade Poppibuster has an affinity tree requirement to watch 70 Heart-To-Hearts.

Comment: Sure, that's a requirement, but that doesn't have any bearing on bonus or not.